# Kubernetes : why are my requests redirected to different pods although I set sessionAffinity to ClientIP?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, session-affinity

In my headless service, I configure sessionAffinity so that **connections from a particular client are passed to the same Pod each time** [as described here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)

Here is the manifest :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 30
```

I run some nginx pods to test :

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=stenote/nginx-hostname
```

The problem is that when I curl my service, I am redirected to different pods and sessionAffinity seems to be ignored.

```
$ kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 --rm utils -it --image arunvelsriram/utils bash
root@utils:/# for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do curl service1; done
nginx-78d58889-b7fm2
nginx-78d58889-b7fm2
nginx-78d58889-b7fm2
nginx-78d58889-b7fm2
nginx-78d58889-b7fm2
nginx-78d58889-8rpxd
nginx-78d58889-b7fm2
nginx-78d58889-62jlw
nginx-78d58889-8rpxd
nginx-78d58889-62jlw
```

NB. When I check with

```
$ kubectl describe  svc service1
Name:              service1
Namespace:         abdelghani
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                None
IPs:               <none>
Session Affinity:  ClientIP
Events:            <none>
```

`SessionAffinity` configuration is present.

Note that my service is headless i.e. `clusterIP: None`. SessionAffinity seems to work fine with non-headless services. But, I cant find a clear explanation in the documentation. Is this related to the platform not doing any proxying?

Abdelghani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using headless service (clusterIP: None) you don't use proxy.

From [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services):

> For headless Services, a cluster IP is not allocated, kube-proxy does
> not handle these Services, and there is no load balancing or proxying
> done by the platform for them. How DNS is automatically configured
> depends on whether the Service has selectors defined

So when using headless service, dns responds with randomized list of ips of all pods associated with given service.

```
/app # dig service1 +search +short
172.17.0.8
172.17.0.10
172.17.0.9
/app # dig service1 +search +short
172.17.0.9
172.17.0.10
172.17.0.8
/app # dig service1 +search +short
172.17.0.8
172.17.0.10
172.17.0.9
/app # dig service1 +search +short
172.17.0.10
172.17.0.9
172.17.0.8
/app # dig service1 +search +short
172.17.0.9
172.17.0.8
172.17.0.10
```

and curl just gets one and goes with it.

Since this hapens every request, every time you get different ip from dns, you connect to different pod.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Do you think this more related to proxying or loadBalancing?

Comment: What is related to what? What are you refering to as ***this***?

Comment: I meant this behavior. The fact that sessionAffinity does not work with headless services

Comment: In this case I'd say its more related to loadbalancing, because proxy is used to forward requests and in this case packets are not forwarded. You just get the random ip and connect to it directly, without any proxy in the middle.